# What's the best way to approximate the area of unshaded region?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to approximate the area of the unshaded region of the picture given below.

[image]

I'd like to fit the best circle in the unshaded area if possible.

Comment: The area of the unshaded region is of course infinite, since you have a point set. The appearance of a "hole" is an illusion.

Comment: could you give a little more background to the problem? for instance where the points came from and why you want to approximate the "unshaded" circle in the middle. as of now, the best advice I can give is to approximate the diameter, $d \approx 75$, and use $A = \pi (\frac d 2)^2=\frac{5625}{4}\pi$, but this is just an approximation for the area of the circle that "seems to appear" in the middle. As Parcly said, if these truly are a bunch of points, then there isn't really a hole.